# Slider too fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, slider

I have a slider on my website, the slider works almost perfectly. What happens is after some time the sliders moves too fast and 10s after moving too fast the slider goes back to normal

This is my code:

```
<section id="slider" class="container-slider large-12 column">
    <ul class="slider-wrapper">
    <li class="current-slide"><a href="historia.html">
      <img src="img/slide-photo.png" alt="slide 1" title="" alt="" class="">

      <div class="slider-icon">
        <img src="img/cat-photo.png" class="icon-slider" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h2 class="slider-title">Cavalo Lusitano</h2>
        <p>O Cavalo Lusitano é procurado como montada de desporto e de lazer e como reprodutor pelas suas raras qualidade de caráter e antiguidade genética, continuando a ser o cavalo por excelência para a Arte Equestre e para o Toureiro.</p>
      </div>
    </a></li>

    <li>
      <img src="img/test2.jpg" title="" alt="">

      <div class="slider-icon">
        <img src="img/cat-photo.png" class="icon-slider" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h2 class="slider-title">Cavalo Lusitano</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo iusto placeat aliquid tempore harum, similique!</p>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img src="img/test1.jpg" title="" alt="">

      <div class="slider-icon">
        <img src="img/cat-photo.png" class="icon-slider" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h2 class="slider-title">Cavalo Lusitano</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos dicta laudantium voluptatem minima! Dolorum tempore dolores excepturi omnis provident. Commodi quis aperiam maiores, dolore a perferendis!</p>
      </div>
    </li>

    </ul>

    <ul id="buttons-slider" class="buttons-slider"></ul>
  </section>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function () {
var currentIndex = 0,
    lightboxLis = jQuery(".light-box li");

var list = [];

jQuery('.thumbnail li').click(function () {

    lightboxLis.eq(currentIndex).show();

    jQuery('.buttons').show();

    jQuery('.container-lightbox').css('height', '100%');

});
 if(lightboxLis.length <= 7){
 for(i=0; i<lightboxLis.length; i++){
  jQuery('<li title="'+i+'"></li>').appendTo('.list');
};
}
else{
for(a=0; a < 5; a++){
jQuery('<li class="esconder"></li>').appendTo('.list');
}
}

var currentLi = jQuery('.list li').attr('title');

if(currentLi == lightboxLis.eq(currentIndex)) {
    jQuery('.list li').addClass('active');
} else {
    jQuery('.list li').removeClass('active');
}

jQuery('.list li').click(function(){
    var current = jQuery(this).attr('title');

    lightboxLis.hide();
    lightboxLis.eq(current).show();
});


jQuery('.next').click(function() {
    currentIndex++;
    if (currentIndex == lightboxLis.length) {
        currentIndex = 0;
    }

    lightboxLis.hide();
    lightboxLis.eq(currentIndex).show();
    console.log(lightboxLis.eq(currentIndex));       
});

jQuery('.prev').click(function() {
    currentIndex--;
    if (currentIndex < 0) {
        currentIndex = lightboxLis.length - 1;
    }

    lightboxLis.hide();
    lightboxLis.eq(currentIndex).show();        
});

 jQuery('.close').click(function() {
  lightboxLis.hide();
  jQuery('.buttons').hide();
  jQuery('.container-lightbox').css('height', '0');
 });
});
```

CSS:

```
.container-slider {
 margin: 0px auto 0;
}


.container-slider-historia {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container-slider-historia img {
  width: 100%;
}


.slider-wrapper {
  z-index: 500;
  position: relative;
  height: 410px;
  background: #transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.slider-wrapper li {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-wrapper .current-slide {
  display: block;
}


.slider-wrapper img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.icon-slider {
  z-index: 999;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

.slide-historia {
  height: 427px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hover-slider {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 460px;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 98%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}

.hover-slider h6 {
  color: white;
  font-family: BlissProBold;
  padding: auto 0;
}


.slider-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(253, 253, 253, 0);
  color: #FFF;
  z-index: 999999;
  margin: 10px 25px 0 0;
  min-height: 60px;
  min-width: 60px;
}

.slider-wrapper .caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
  width: 46%;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  min-height: 30%;
  margin-top: 125px;
}


.slider-wrapper h2 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.slider-wrapper p {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 200;
}


.control-buttons {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999; 
  width: 95%;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

.control-buttons li {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #d1d3d4;
  text-indent: -99999px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  margin: 0 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.control-buttons li.active {
  background: #cb301c;
  border: 2px solid white;
}


.buttons-slider {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 95%;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

.buttons-slider li {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #d1d3d4;
  text-indent: -99999px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  margin: 0 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.buttons-slider li.active {
  background: #cb301c;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.authors {
  text-align: center;
  color: #7a8699;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 80px;
  font-size: 300;
}

.arrows {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Paste your css, please.

Comment: Edited above, thanks for replying